# Is it possible to compute Pearson correlation coefficient in parallel?

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

Let be $X = \{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ and $Y = \{y_1, ..., y_n\}$ two vectors of the same length $n$.

Is it possible to compute the Pearson correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$ in parallel?

More precisely, is it possible to compute $\rho = \operatorname{corr}(X,Y)$ by computing $\rho_1 = \operatorname{corr}(X_1,Y)$ and $\rho_2 = \operatorname{corr}(X_2,Y)$ separately where $X_1 = \{x_1, ..., x_{n/2}\}$ and $X_2 = \{x_{n/2 + 1}, ..., x_{n}\}$?

Comment: I am assuming the capital letter stands for random variable and the corresponding lower-case letters stand for its realizations (the data observed) respectively. In traditional frequentist set up, we often assuming the pair $(x_i, y_i)$ are i.i.d. - the dependency only occur within a pair. So without observing that pair all together, you cannot estimate the correlation. Please correct me if these assumptions do not fit into your question.

Comment: @BGM Your assumptions are totally correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the Pearson correlation, you will need to compute the variance and the covariance of the two operations. While the computation of correlation cannot be splitted, it is perfectly possible to split the computation of variance and covariance.

To see this, suppose that we are dealing with the variance, which is defined as $\frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i^2 - (\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i)^2$. This is nothing but a summation and can be implemented using a pattern known as *reduction*. One implementation on CUDA can be found [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf), or the famous [map reduce](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html)